# Nextcloud Helm Chart Change Max Upload Size

Tags: kubernetes, nextcloud, helm

I deployed the [Nextcloud Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nextcloud) to my cluster.  Installation went fine and I can use it.  But I can only upload small files (the default).

How can I configure the helm chart to allow larger files (5Gi) to be uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the variable `client_max_body_size 10G;` in the NGINX config (https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nextcloud/templates/nginx-config.yaml#L97).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way I found to solve this was to use nextcloud:19-fpm as the image and enable nginx.